# How to make classic theme work only for one jsp

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am working on a portlet on which my own custom theme is applied. But there is a `view.jsp` page where i am displaying `search container` of `liferay` and that `search container` looks ugly in my custom theme. 
is there a way i can use classic theme only for my `view.jsp` page?

Comment: Fix your custom there with correct css which makes search container better OR use css from classic them for search container tags

Comment: @PankajKathiriya Is there a way i can get the classic theme code for search container

Comment: You may want to have a look into css files `/liferay-portal-src-6.2-ee/portal-web/docroot/html/css/taglib/search_container.css
/liferay-portal-src-6.2-ee/portal-web/docroot/html/css/taglib/search_iterator.css`